# How to use/define a customized parameter?

Tags: pstricks, parameters, pstricks-add

I´m generating any grpahs... and I´m playing with any linewidhts values so I would like to type on the beginning of the .TEX a line similar to

```
width1=0.1cm
width2=0.15cm
width2=0.20cm
```

to avoid chaging all the values of linewidth trough all the lines in the graphs. So, I would change only, and I view all the lines with that width.

```
   width1=0.32cm
```

How can I do this?

I suposse this is easy, but I can´t find the answer.

-- That´s my doubt --- and in the next lines I type my .tex file, where I can´t reach a good way to do an amount as a parameter

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}  % Margenes de la normativa TFG

\usepackage{setspace} % para que no afecte el interlineado a las notas de pié de página
\setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathpazo}       % Fuente MathPazo
\usepackage{datetime}       % paquete para configurar formato de fecha y hora
\settimeformat{ampmtime}
\renewcommand*{\noon}{\pmname}
\spanishdecimal{.}
% ----------------------  PSTRICKS ---------------
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-3dplot,pst-node,pst-tree,pst-grad,pst-coil,pst-text,pst-3d,pst-eps,pst-fill,pstricks-add,multido}
% -------- Paquetes de pst-all \usepackage{pst-all}   paquete pstricks para las figuras en postcript
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
% ---- Fin Paquetes de pst-all

w1=0.085cm          (HERE I WANT TO DEFINE A PARAMETER)
w2=0.1cm                (HERE I WANT TO DEFINE A PARAMETER)
w3=0.15cm             (HERE I WANT TO DEFINE A PARAMETER)
w4=0.30cm            (HERE I WANT TO DEFINE A PARAMETER)


\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm}
  \begin{pspicture}(-0,-0)(7.28,4.5) %\malla
 \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none](-.0,0)(7.28,4.5)

 \rput(1,1){\circlenode{1}{\textcolor{black}{1}}}
 \rput(1,3){\circlenode{2}{\textcolor{black}{2}}}
 \rput(3,2){\circlenode{3}{\textcolor{black}{3}}}
 \rput(3,4){\circlenode{4}{\textcolor{black}{4}}}
 \rput(5,1){\circlenode{5}{\textcolor{black}{5}}}
 \rput(5,3){\circlenode{6}{\textcolor{black}{6}}}
 \rput(7,2){\circlenode{7}{\textcolor{black}{7}}}

 \ncline[linewidth=w1]{-}{1}{2}\naput{\scriptsize $2$} (IN THIS LINE I WANT TO USE A PARAMETER)
 \ncline{-}{1}{3}\naput{\scriptsize $6$}
 \ncline{-}{1}{4}\naput{\scriptsize $4$}
 \ncline{-}{1}{5}\naput{\scriptsize $6$}
 \ncline{-}{2}{4}\naput{\scriptsize $7$}
 \ncline[linewidth=w2]{-}{2}{3}\naput{\scriptsize $3$} (IN THIS LINE I WANT TO USE A PARAMETER)
 \ncline[linewidth=w3]{-}{3}{4}\naput{\scriptsize $5$} (IN THIS LINE I WANT TO USE A PARAMETER)
 \ncline{-}{3}{5}\naput{\scriptsize $4$}
 \ncline{-}{3}{6}\naput{\scriptsize $9$}
 \ncline{-}{3}{7}\naput{\scriptsize $3$}
 \ncline{-}{4}{6}\naput{\scriptsize $3$}
 \ncline[linewidth=0.12cm]{-}{4}{5}\naput{\scriptsize $4$}
 \ncline[linewidth=0.12cm]{-}{5}{6}\naput{\scriptsize $6$}
 \ncline{-}{5}{7}\naput{\scriptsize $8$}
 \ncline[linewidth=0.12cm]{-}{6}{7}\naput{\scriptsize $4$}

 \nccurve[angleA=335,angleB=255,linewidth=0.12cm]{-}{1}{7}\naput{\scriptsize $4$}

 \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `width1=0.32cm` and `width2=\dimexper\0.2\width1\relax` is what you want?

Comment: @HarishKumar: I think the question is more about defining new keys with PSTricks.

Comment: \harish-kumar That solutions gives me problem!! No solution

Comment: @Mika Could you please edit your post and make it fully compilable example? It would help the solvers tremendously.

Comment: \malipivo ok, I have done it, but we have just the solution by Christoph

Comment: To notify you should use `@` not \ like @harishkumar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PSTricks you can use `\pslinewidth`, which is the current linewidth. If you use that through the document, you can later scale the linewidth of all lines.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psset{linewidth=3pt}
  \psline(0,1)(5,1)
  \psline(0,2)(5,2)
  \psline[linewidth=2\pslinewidth](0,3)(5,3)
  \psline[linewidth=3\pslinewidth](0,4)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to change the line properties of only a few lines, you can use e.g. `\newpsstyle` to define some line styles at one, centralized point in your document:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\newpsstyle{LineA}{linewidth=2\pslinewidth, linecolor=green}
\newpsstyle{LineB}{linewidth=3\pslinewidth, linecolor=red}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psset{linewidth=3pt}
  \psline(0,1)(5,1)
  \psline(0,2)(5,2)
  \psline[style=LineA](0,3)(5,3)
  \psline[style=LineB](0,4)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just to mention a few possibilities.

Comment: Fantastic Solution!! Thank you. This is neccessary defined in each pstricks image, or Can I define for all the .TEX for every pstricks images.

Comment: You can of course define a file `mysettings.tex` which contains only the `\newpsstyle` or `\newpsobject` (see Herbert's answer) definitions and load that into every other file with `\input{mysettings}`.

Comment: a curisity !!  for  objects and styles You must use \newpsobjet and \newpsstyle. and... where can I find more things that can be defined in the way you show me?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\newpsobject{pslineA}{psline}{linewidth=6\pslinewidth, linecolor=green}
\newpsobject{pslineB}{psline}{linewidth=10\pslinewidth, linecolor=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
  \psline(0,1)(5,1)
  \psline[linewidth=1mm](0,2)(5,2)
  \pslineA(0,3)(5,3)
  \pslineB(0,4)(5,4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I´m sorry for not be available choose 2 answers as THE ANSWER! It´s fantastic have 2 good answers.